# org.json.JSONObject creating JSONObject from string threw java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, json, org.json

I've been trying to figure out why constructing a `org.json.JSONObject` from a string json would not work for very long.

Here is the json string (pretty)

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "200 Request is valid",
    "job": {
        "Id": 1,
        "Jobtitle": "Test Job",
        "Description": "Asthma",
        "Medicalcondition": "Asthma",
        "Language": "English",
        "Racereligion": "Chinese",
        "Agegender": "50, Female",
        "Hourlyprice": 42,
        "Type": "caregiver",
        "Date": "2019-05-12T00:00:00+08:00",
        "Starttime": "2018-07-20T12:15:00+08:00",
        "Endtime": "2018-07-20T18:15:00+08:00",
        "Address": "1 Cluny Road",
        "Latitude": 1.3152057,
        "Longitude": 103.8162553,
        "Creator": "xiurobert"
    }
}
```

and minified (the one that I'm attempting to construct a JSONObject from)

```
String json = "{\"status\":200,\"message\":\"200 Request is valid\",\"job\":{\"Id\":1,\"Jobtitle\":\"Test Job\",\"Description\":\"Asthma\",\"Medicalcondition\":\"Asthma\",\"Language\":\"English\",\"Racereligion\":\"Chinese\",\"Agegender\":\"50, Female\",\"Hourlyprice\":42,\"Type\":\"caregiver\",\"Date\":\"2019-05-12T00:00:00+08:00\",\"Starttime\":\"2018-07-20T12:15:00+08:00\",\"Endtime\":\"2018-07-20T18:15:00+08:00\",\"Address\":\"1 Cluny Road\",\"Latitude\":1.3152057,\"Longitude\":103.8162553,\"Creator\":\"xiurobert\"}}";
```

Constructor

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json)
```

However, this resulted in a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()`

I've even tried using gson to parse the string first and then output it back to the new JSONObject but it seems like it didn't work.

Any reasons why?

Comment: which version of the library are you using? I am not able to reproduce the issue in json-20180130.jar   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180130

Comment: @karthick im using the one bundled with android api 26. Not sure which one that would be

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly

```
String json = "{\"status\":200,\"message\":\"200 Request is valid\",\"job\":{\"Id\":1,\"Jobtitle\":\"Test Job\",\"Description\":\"Asthma\",\"Medicalcondition\":\"Asthma\",\"Language\":\"English\",\"Racereligion\":\"Chinese\",\"Agegender\":\"50, Female\",\"Hourlyprice\":42,\"Type\":\"caregiver\",\"Date\":\"2019-05-12T00:00:00+08:00\",\"Starttime\":\"2018-07-20T12:15:00+08:00\",\"Endtime\":\"2018-07-20T18:15:00+08:00\",\"Address\":\"1 Cluny Road\",\"Latitude\":1.3152057,\"Longitude\":103.8162553,\"Creator\":\"xiurobert\"}}";
        try
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            Log.i("TAG", "a: "+jsonObject.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

where are you getting error

Comment: I'm getting a JSONException thrown whenever I am trying to create a string

Comment: the above code is working fine, so you want to create a string from that jsonObject?

Comment: if you want to create a string from that jsonObject just call the jsonObject.toString() simple, or if you want something else tell in details.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I need to use the org.json library and I'm trying to do it in a unit rest for android

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have used `org.json.JSONObject` and `org.json.JSONArray`. Then i changed the imports to `org.json.simple.JSONObject` and `org.json.simple.JSONArray` and my code worked without any issues.